# jQuery CheckBox Selector .attr('checked) is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a checkbox called chkBox1 and i want assign a variable true or false as per the value of selected checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox1">

var chkBox1Val = $('#chkBox1').attr('checked') ? true: false;
```

The above code is not working. How do i get the value of checkbox checked state and assigned to a variable as true/false?

Answer (score 5):

```
var chkBox1Val = $('#chkBox1').attr('checked') === 'checked';
```

Or, if you are using jQuery version greater than 1.6:

```
var chkBox1Val = $('#chkBox1').prop('checked');
```

For more info, have a look at the [section *Attributes vs. Properties* of the jQuery `.prop()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
var chkBox1Val = $('#chkBox1').is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var ckbox = $('#chkBox1');
    $('input').on('click',function () {
        if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
            alert('You have Checked it');
        } else {
            alert('You Un-Checked it');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox1">
```